# .NET Framework Newtsonsoft json customize required exception message

Tags: c#, json.net, .net-4.8

Suppose I have the following class definition

```
public class Person
{
    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And when I try to instantiate a new `Person` from the following text: `"{}"`, I will get an exception

```
try
{
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>("{}");
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    // ex.Message = 'Required property 'Name' not found in JSON. Path '', line 1, position 2.'
}
```

**How can I customize this error message?** I have several classes with several properties per class and I'd like to simplify these errors to send back to the client. Something like

> Unable to create person, 'Name' is required.

I wish not to send internal JSON exceptions to the client. I also tried a custom JsonConverter

```
public class Person
{
    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(MyCustomConverter))]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

but the custom converter's methods like `ReadJson` is not even being called when the property does not exist. Note that in the exact application I am not calling `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` myself, it is automatically done in my Api endpoints so solutions like

```
try
{
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(input);
}
catch(JsonException jex)
{
    throw new JsonException("My custom message")
}
```

are really not helpful. It also does not scale to every single other property in all other classes.

Comment: My 2 cents is that I wouldn't leave my validation to my JSON serializer.

Comment: But where would you?

Comment: Well, I'm doing it in an ASP.NET Core-based API, and I'm using FluentValidation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use original exception as `InnerException`. In order to do that you need to use `Exception`'s constructor overload with message and inner exception:

```
catch(Exception ex)
{
    throw new Exception("Unable to create person, 'Name' is required.", ex);
}
```

This way you will keep all relevant information about exception in `InnerException`, while being able to define customized exception message.

Also, if you want to use `JsonException`, it also has the same [constructor overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonexception.-ctor?view=net-8.0#system-text-json-jsonexception-ctor(system-string-system-exception)).

You could also specify you custom exception class for that purpose.

Comment: This is exactly what I want to avoid. First of all, I do not manually do that serialization. My app is a web API that runs on IIS. So serialization is done for me by the container. I would somehow like to configure the message and/or the exception when the property is missing

Comment: Maybe you could use middleware defined such as `app.Use(async (context,next) => {})`, and inside it you could wrap it in `try..catch` block and use my code snippet.